How do i check for & filter by multiple unique arguments in google sheets?
I currently am majually going through Google Sheet spreadsheets that include peoples' names, and charitable groups they've donated to, with each donation being a new line. I am currently trying to find a way to easily isolate just people who have donated to 2 or more charities, so i would need to use a formula/function that checks for unique names, and then searches rows with each unique name and shows/isolates/sorts only the rows where a specific individual has donated to more than one charity. The issue is that in many many cases, people donate to the same charity twice, so it can't just be # of instances of a given unique name.
I've attached a sample sheet that has all the info replaced with anonomized info but its effectively the same setup, plus an example of what data i want seperated.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1heECQb9D9TzCAjQsU8-Ij1wUI-cZOsK-N3LXAGX3-Fo/edit?usp=sharing
Thank you in advance!

Is that the ideal expected output you showcased in the test sheet OR just a visual representation?!

Its an example of which data i want separated; that would be an acceptable output, but really anything that sorts the data into those two groups in a way that is visible is acceptable. (just a representation, but would be okay as an output)

Can you manually enter & showcase the expected output for the test input data you provided...

I just updated the sheet to have the ideal output. Thanks for helping.


You may try:
=filter(A2:R25,let(Σ,Q2:Q25,xmatch(Σ,reduce(,unique(Σ),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,if(countuniqueifs(B2:B25,Σ,c)>1,c,)))))))



This is perfect! Thank you so much!

There is another workaround if you want to have more control on the data that you are filtering, you can use App Script code for filter and show on the same page the information or in another page with a more structure output.
Try this code:
function filterMultipleCharitiesWithoutDupes() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.shift(); // Remove header row

  // Find the column index of 'contributor_Full_Name' and 'Charity_name'
  var nameCol = headers.indexOf('contributor_Full_Name');
  var charityCol = headers.indexOf('Charity_name');

  // Create a dictionary to store contributors and their unique charities
  var contributors = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[nameCol];
    var charity = row[charityCol];

    if (!contributors[name]) {
      contributors[name] = [];
    }
    if (!contributors[name].includes(charity)) {
      contributors[name].push(charity);
    }
  }

  // Filter data based on contributors with multiple charities
  var filteredData = [];
  for (var name in contributors) {
    if (contributors[name].length > 1) {
      // Only add unique rows for each contributor
      var addedRows = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        if (row[nameCol] == name && !addedRows[row.join('_')]) {
          filteredData.push(row);
          addedRows[row.join('_')] = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Add headers to the beginning of the filtered data
  filteredData.unshift(headers);

  // Create a new sheet with the filtered data
  var newSheet = sheet.getParent().insertSheet('Filtered Data Without Dupes');
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
  
}

On the spreadsheet file go to the extensions option, then app script and paste the code example

I hope this works for you and helps you to filter the data
